# It seems onChange="myFunction()" is only calling my function once?

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following HTML that is within a form, to accept 2 numbers from two separate inputs

```
<input type="number" id="amount" name="amount" value="0" onchange="ltv()">
<input type="number" id="property_value" name="property_value" value="0" onchange="ltv()">
<p id="ltv"></p>
```

Then some JavaScript

```
function ltv() {
    var amount = document.getElementById("amount").textContent;
    var property_value = document.getElementById("property_value").textContent;
    document.getElementById("ltv").innerHTML = Math.round(amount/property_value*100);
};
```

However after entering a number into the "amount" input the ltv element is updated with NaN which is to be expected at this stage as only the first variable in the math operation is set, however upon entering the second number and tabbing away from the input field the ltv is not updated again.

Comment: Did you check with the browser inspecter function that script execution isn't simply stopped on first error ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like `textContent` isn't returning anything. Try to use `.value`

```
function ltv() {
    var amount = document.getElementById("amount").value;
    var property_value = document.getElementById("property_value").value;
    document.getElementById("ltv").innerHTML = Math.round(amount/property_value*100);
};
```